# resize UIWebView frame,the contents coverd

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Use this method `[webView loadHTMLString:text baseURL:nil]`add content,

and resize the webView , then the contents coverd.

---

[image: webViewScrrengif]
I wonder why my content not show well . I try to find out witch one has cover it, but failed.

any one can tell me how to show content correctly;

`I hope content to adapt to screen ,like div works for browser.
 Need more help...`

Comment: how you are showing content on UIWebview..?

Comment: use 'loadHTMLString:baseURL' , the html string is a div ,`<div style= " line-height:1;"> ******* </div>`

Comment: did u use this ....
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

Comment: @Sabareesh  It's seems that the contet not work well.  I upload new screenShots .